# running my tmux panes automatically

Tags: tmux

Inspiring from [this](https://www.hackzine.org/auto-starting-tmux-with-panes-services.html) blog post I tried to run my project on 20 tmux panes with different inputs at once as below.

~/foo/tmux_project_session.sh file consists the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/tmux source-file

new-session -d
split-window -d -t 0 -v
split-window -d -t 0 -v
split-window -d -t 0 -v
split-window -d -t 0 -v
split-window -d -t 0 -v
split-window -d -t 0 -v
split-window -d -t 0 -v
split-window -d -t 0 -v
split-window -d -t 0 -v
split-window -d -t 0 -v
split-window -d -t 0 -v
split-window -d -t 0 -v
split-window -d -t 0 -v
split-window -d -t 0 -v
split-window -d -t 0 -v
split-window -d -t 0 -v
split-window -d -t 0 -v
split-window -d -t 0 -v
split-window -d -t 0 -v
split-window -d -t 0 -v

prefix="cd ~/foo/ && source virtualenv/bin/activate && python project.py"

suffix="-p parameter"

send-keys -t 0 "${prefix} variable_1 ${suffix}" enter 
send-keys -t 1 "${prefix} variable_2 ${suffix}" enter 
send-keys -t 2 "${prefix} variable_3 ${suffix}" enter 
send-keys -t 3 "${prefix} variable_4 ${suffix}" enter 
send-keys -t 4 "${prefix} variable_5 ${suffix}" enter 

send-keys -t 5 "${prefix} variable_6 ${suffix}" enter 
send-keys -t 6 "${prefix} variable_7 ${suffix}" enter 
send-keys -t 7 "${prefix} variable_8 ${suffix}" enter 
send-keys -t 8 "${prefix} variable_9 ${suffix}" enter 
send-keys -t 9 "${prefix} variable_10 ${suffix}" enter 

send-keys -t 10 "${$prefix} variable_11 ${suffix}" enter 
send-keys -t 11 "${$prefix} variable_12 ${suffix}" enter 
send-keys -t 12 "${$prefix} variable_13 ${suffix}" enter 
send-keys -t 13 "${$prefix} variable_14 ${suffix}" enter 
send-keys -t 14 "${$prefix} variable_15 ${suffix}" enter

send-keys -t 15 "${$prefix} variable_16 ${suffix}" enter 
send-keys -t 16 "${$prefix} variable_17 ${suffix}" enter 
send-keys -t 17 "${$prefix} variable_18 ${suffix}" enter 
send-keys -t 18 "${$prefix} variable_19 ${suffix}" enter 
send-keys -t 19 "${$prefix} variable_20 ${suffix}" enter 


select-pane -t 3

attach
```

I run this code as an argument as below:

```
tmux -CC source-file ~/foo/tmux_project_session.sh
```

It runs tmux -CC and create 4 vertical panes. Runs as it should be on the 2nd, 3rd and 4th panes. It does not do anything on the 1st pane.

Could you please advise me on what would be my error on my script?

What prevent 1st pane to work with variable_1 and why wouldn't the rest of panes even start?

Thanks